# Error in Yootheme's ZOO after submitting a comment

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I keep on getting this error after a post is submitted:  `DATE_FORMAT_COMMENTS | #`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the text is uppercase points to this being an untranslated string used within the code but that doesn't match a string in the appropriate language file.

If you can locate the appropriate language file you could add the string and its value directly.  Look in /languages/en-GB/com_zoo.ini orfor a file with a similar name in /components/com_zoo/languages/

Alternatively, contact the developers for an upgrade or fix.